# Close files handlers used by processing:runalg("qgis.difference"......) or os.popen("gdalwarp -q -cutline.......)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, close

How can I do to close all files used by functions that I use in my plugin like

```
processing:runalg("qgis.difference"......) 

os.popen("gdalwarp -q -cutline.......)
```

After runing my function, if I want to run it another time, I have to close QGIS and reload it again.

Comment: I have not tried it, but what if you do `with os.popen("gdalwarp -q -cutline.......):` and next line indentate `pass`